# Scala : How to convert Int to Number type for the purpose of using in bar chart?

Tags: scala, javafx, scalafx, typecasting-operator

In scala , how does one achieve converting type Int to Number?

```
var A : Int = 10
```

How do i convert A to number type?
I want to plot a bar chart using scalafx, and NumberAxis accept number as the data.
So , i will need to convert Int to Number.
How do i achieve that?
Thank you

Comment: where does this `Number` comes from? Provide links or you won't get any help.

Comment: A is an integer..
Which is the data that i want to display on the bar chart..
And in bar chart, if i am not mistaken, for NumberAxis, the type must be Number..
I am confused on how to change it to Number..
From what i read Number is in java..
@pedrofurla

Comment: Never mind.....

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [API](http://www.scalafx.org/api/2.2/index.html#scalafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis)? I see a method called `toRealValue` which takes in a `Double` and returns a `Number`. You can do `toRealValue(A.toDouble)`

Comment: There are implicit conversions from the Scala native numeric types to the boxed Java Number types (in `Predef`).  So, in most cases you shouldn't need to do anything.  Can you give an example of what you want to do that doesn't work?